# sending a form fields name using a variable and text php /codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

If i had a form input field such as

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

i know i can name the field dynamically like this

```
<?php

$name = 'name';

?>

<input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>">
```

i can also add a text string after the variable like this

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $name; ?>secondname">
```

that would now be called 'namesecondname'

what i need to know is if this is possible to get in codeigniter controller after the form has been submitted.

for example lets assume this is my form

```
<?php

 $hello = 'hello';
 

?>
 
 <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="<?php echo $hello; ?>">
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $hello; ?>world" value="some value">
```

My field name is now 'helloworld' then in my controller i want to get it like this :

```
$var = $this->input->post('somename');
$field = $this->input->post($var.'world');
```

$field = 'some value' but how do i use a variable and text dynamically as the inputs name?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$_POST`. It will get all the post value, then you can iterate to get name & value

```
$postdata = $_POST;

foreach($postdata as $key => $value)
{
    //key is your input name, and value is the input value
    //do your operation
}
```